# Crystal Report Viewer button is not working in Google chrome and Firefox but fine in IE

Tags: asp.net, firefox, c#-4.0, google-chrome, crystal-reports-2010

Mine is asp.net with c# web application. Crystal Report Print button is not working in Google chrome and Firefox but fine in IE. **When I click on print button of Crystal Report Viewer it just refresh the web page and doesn't display any dialog in Google chrome**. In Firefox it opens the print dialog box, now i'm clicking the cancel button. Then i click Logout, its simply staying in the same page, while clicking any other links after clicking Logout it navigates to Session expire page. **I don't have this issue in IE**. CrystalReportViewer is not placed with in Update panel.

Comment: Have you deployed this website? What runtime version are you using? Try developer toolbar (F12) on Chrome.. is there an error?

Comment: The Crystal Report Viewer doesn’t support Google Chrome. (See https://cw.sdn.sap.com/cw/ideas/3136 for more details.) If anyone knows of a work around for this that would be very helpful.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco: Thanks for your reply. Using II7 to deploy my application. There was no error while using developer toolbar (F12) on chrome.

Comment: sorry @davids. by mistaken i told that i had solved it. still it is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have this in your assemblies in the web.config

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

I added this assembly and the print button started working for me in all browsers. However its not a true print in Chrome it exports the report to PDF then you can print from the file.

Answer (score 2):

Additional with CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc assembly try set option:

```
   CrystalReportViewer1.PDFOneClickPrinting = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try using the report object instead the viewer, you can use its PrintToPrinter property in other to print and using the viewer control for just viewing (maybe adding another print button for that matter).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have th is in your aspnet_client file adding and PrintContol.cab also includeing on your appliction . I hope its working on Firefox but chrome not working ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ4Oi.png)